# Cannot run flutter webview on ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm trying to run flutter webview app on iOS simulator but it keeps giving me error.
Tried everything, but still same message.

```
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
  arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
Exited
```

Any help is welcome.
Android works well. This is only for iOS.

Working on Macbook Pro 2020 M1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Also make sure you added this in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Terminal: https://prnt.sc/0filOO5udyos
info.plist: https://prnt.sc/DSuP0Boqk8C0

Comment: And got this...

https://pastebin.com/pPTUmCmg

Comment: Wrong screenshot i think. Add the keys that's in the answer to your info.plist file of it's missing. Then navigate to ios folder through terminal and execute the command that's in the answer. Then try building it

Comment: Delete Podfile.lock, Pods folder and .symlinks folder and run `arch -x86_64 pod install` then try building it

Comment: Here you go: https://prnt.sc/32JFIE7KHcax

Now error: https://pastebin.com/SFe7591N

Comment: Same after deleting and running command

Comment: Open the runner.xcworkspace in Xcode and build it from Xcode once

Comment: Also you can try `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o1Hp822j8EJv

Comment: Can I get your e-mail or discord or something? I really appreciate your time and willingness to help me.

Comment: Not sure if its ok to add it here. But we can move this to chat. You try once after repo update and building it on xcode

Comment: Terminal: https://prnt.sc/nH1u3qnHG2EB
xcode: https://prnt.sc/cQPkTVXNppwc

Comment: Cool this means your pods is not installed properly. Please do these steps. Delete Pods folder, delete Podfile.lock, delete .symlinks folder. Then execute `arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`. Open runner.xcworkspace in Xcode. On the top you will see some warnings. Click that and click on the warning on the left and in the pop up click resolve. Then select a simulator and hit play button

Comment: Also please add your Podfile in the question

Comment: https://prnt.sc/9SLqVWBD3pk3 same
PODFILE CHECKSUM: e1cc1b9bfcee40b7e3b024bb1f267ea59b724d03

COCOAPODS: 1.11.3

Comment: Also I contacted you on twitter

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an M1 chip

Run

```
sudo gem uninstall ffi
```

and

```
sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Add this to your info.plist

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```